# What should I do If I want to get the currencies rates from a web service to my android programme?

Tags: android, programming-languages

I would like to get the currencies information from :http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml to my android programme and update constantly

Answer (score 1):

You want to read an XML file... here is a tutorial on how to do it :

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/

To update constantly you just have to reload the XML data every minute (for example) and update your interface to show the new values.

Answer (score 0):

I read this before, but I don't know how to get the information from
http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml 
Because the two XMLs semm different